# Start position of text style by CSS different position of text on PDF file

Tags: pdf, zend-framework, tcpdf

I have a issue when using TCPDF to edit PDF file. This issue happen on Zend PDF also.
Look at attach image.
[Position of text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSF1C.png)

The green text use css style, it stay center of vertical of green rectangle, the foot of "g" character stay in bottom of green rectangle.
But when I write this text using TCPDF(or Zend PDF) at the same position, the foot of "H" character stay in bottom of green rectangle (not foot of "g" character), that mean the text is outside the box(include "g" character).

Can you explain me why the start position of text using PDF library not same CSS style?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It takes much time to programmatically generate PDF. Much easier way would be using PDF generator that can take HTML as an input.

I'm involved in the project called pdfapi.io https://pdfapi.io. It can convert regular web pages with CSS styles and JavaScript to PDF documents. It also has nice PHP SDK as well.

And if you are using Zend Framework 2 or 3 you can use it as a module: https://github.com/pdfapi/zf2-pdfapi-module

Service is free of charge.

*Hope that helps*